# Invalid call of undeclared identifier texture2DLodOffset

Tags: opengl, glsl, antialiasing

I am trying to get this [FXAA shader](http://www.geeks3d.com/20110405/fxaa-fast-approximate-anti-aliasing-demo-glsl-opengl-test-radeon-geforce/3/) run on my machine.

It does not seem to recognize a function named `texture2DLodOffset` in GLSL. It also does not recognize `texture2DLod`. The `texture2DLod` function has apparently had an alternative in `texture2D` as the third argument `bias`. However, I could not find alternative to the former missing function `texture2DLodOffset`. Can somebody get me through this?

It would also be great if somebody could suggest me any more `anti-aliasing` techniques.

Specifications (working on a Virtual Machine):

```
OpenGL vendor string: Parallels and Intel Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Parallels using Intel Iris OpenGL Engine
OpenGL version string: 2.1 INTEL-10.6.20
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`texture2DLodOffset()` is from [`EXT_gpu_shader4`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/gpu_shader4.txt), make sure that's supported on your GL implementation and enabled via:

```
#extension GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 : enable
```

after your `#version` directive.

Or, [the jMonkeyEngine sources](https://code.google.com/p/jmonkeyengine/source/browse/trunk/engine/src/core-data/Common/MatDefs/Post/FXAA.frag?r=9095) have some alternatives:

```
...
#if __VERSION_ >= 130
    #define OffsetVec(a, b) ivec2(a, b)
    #define FxaaTexOff(t, p, o, r) textureOffset(t, p, o)
#elif defined(GL_EXT_gpu_shader4)
    #define OffsetVec(a, b) ivec2(a, b)
    #define FxaaTexOff(t, p, o, r) texture2DLodOffset(t, p, 0.0, o)
#else
    #define OffsetVec(a, b) vec2(a, b)
    #define FxaaTexOff(t, p, o, r) texture2D(t, p + o * r)
#endif
...
```

You'll probably want the last set for `#version 120`:

```
#define OffsetVec(a, b) vec2(a, b)
#define FxaaTexOff(t, p, o, r) texture2D(t, p + o * r)
```